# Lazy loading - Providers and modules

Tags: angular, ionic3, lazy-loading

I'm moving my app to lazy loading. I'm done with pages, pipes and directives but now it's the turn of providers/services and some other modules.

This was my `app.module`:

```
...
import { FileUploadModule } from "ng2-file-upload";
import { CloudinaryModule } from "@cloudinary/angular-5.x";
import * as cloudinary from "cloudinary-core";
import { ImageUploadProvider } from "../services/image-upload/image-upload";
...
imports: [
 ...
 FileUploadModule,
 CloudinaryModule.forRoot(cloudinary, {
   cloud_name: "cloudName",
   upload_preset: "cloudCode"
  }),
  ...
]
providers: [
 ...
 ImageUploadProvider
  ...
]
```

Now, these references are removed from this file.

I need all of this on my `new-recipe` component. For that I added this into `new-recipe.module`:

```
import { ImageUploadProvider } from "../../services/image-upload/image-upload";
...
providers: [
    ImageUploadProvider
  ]
```

What else do I need? I also created a `image-upload.module` but not sure if this is correct:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { FileUploadModule } from "ng2-file-upload";
import { CloudinaryModule } from "@cloudinary/angular-5.x";
import * as cloudinary from "cloudinary-core";
import { ImageUploadProvider } from '../services/image-upload/image-upload';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FileUploadModule,
    CloudinaryModule.forRoot(cloudinary, {
      cloud_name: "cloudName",
      upload_preset: "cloudId"
    })
  ],
  exports: [
    CloudinaryModule
  ]
})

export class ImageUploadProviderModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: ImageUploadProviderModule,
      providers: [ImageUploadProvider] // <-- is this necessary?
    };
  }
}
```

Do I need to import this new module inside `new-recipe.module` and remove the provider reference? How can I access then from my functions in `new-recipe` to this.imageUploadProvider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are lazily loading your recipe module, and new-recipe component is declared in your Recipe module which will use the image imageUploadProvider and this provider will also be used by other components, here is the possible solution:

- If you need the service/Provider only in components inside your recipe module, then you need to remove import of the service from the providers array in app.module, import the service in your Recipe Module like you have done, provide it in it's providers array. After this to use the service simply import the service in your components(which are part of your recipe module), declare the service in the component's constructor and you'll be good to go, repeat the same step for any other component inside Recipe module and they will receive the same instance.
- Now If you want to use the imageUploadProvider in any component across any module and receive the same instance then you'll have to provide it in the root module. For that, you simply need to import the service in your root module(app.module) and declare it in the providers array like you did in your app module earlier:

  `import { ImageUploadProvider } from "../../services/image-upload/image-upload";
  ...
  providers: [
  ImageUploadProvider
  ]`

After this, you will be able to import the service in any component you want and declare it in their constructor and use them. **You should not import this service into any other module and mention it in their providers array, this will create a separate instance.**
If you are doing lazy loading properly and import & declare the service correctly in your components then this solution should work. You can also give a read about shared services in your free time.

Comment: `If you want to use the imageUploadProvider in any component across any module and receive the same instance then you'll have to provide it in the root module` or create a parent component just for these childs which in my opinion is way too much overthinking. Sometimes is better moving to non lazy loading way to avoid spaguetti code in the future

Comment: Another option could be extract the parts that I need to share between these components and create a specific provider to share info so if I need now to save something like this: 
this.imageUploadProvider.image = 'myImage.jpg'` now I'll do this.imageUploadProvider.saveImage() {
// next provider is loaded on app.module
this.sharedInfoProvider.image = 'myImage.jps'; 
}
Is this a good idea?

Comment: so following the previous message, what happens when we import on a lazy loaded provider a provider which hasn't been lazy loaded? Are we going to use 2 instances of the previous one or we're just going to use the general one?

Comment: So If you are going to make every component child of the parent component you'll have to pass data from each component to the other using input or output decorators. which would create a badly nested (spaghetti) code and would hinder separation of concerns and reusing of small components across others. Lazy loading is generally used if your application is very heavy and has different independent functionalities then you can make your main module light by just keeping the required things in your app module and then loading other modules as user requires them,basically making the first load fast

Comment: Fr second comment, extracting common functionalities is one of the primary functions of a service. Even to access the variable 'this.sharedInfoProvider.image' in other components, you'll anyway have to inject the service in them which redirects to your first question.For third comment u can't inject one provider into another provider, you can inject them into components(not ur use case) and modules. Now if you inject the service again into your lazy loaded module, you'll another instance of the same service unless you have used for root methodology https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: Perfect, makes a lot of sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular 6 (might be in 5 too but I don't think so) you might want to simply use:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

I believe this will load services on demand without them being provided in any providers array which should make your life a whole lot easier. This provides a singleton service available to the whole app. Appropriate for stateless services.

You can also specify a `providedIn: moduleName` if that works better for you.

Once again, you don't have to list the service in the module's providers array.

See https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4 for a bit more info. Search for `providedIn`

Comment: I'm using Angular 5. I had a look but it's just available from Angular 6. Wouldn't mind to upgrade but I use Angular with Ionic 3. I need to wait till Ionic 4 for this version of Angular. In the meantime I need to find a different approach

Comment: at the moment I could use `provider: []` inside `@Component` but it doesn't work. Apparently it loses the information between different pages (apart from that I don't get any error)

Comment: You could use ngrx and store your data there, your service can then retrieve data from the ngrx store, ngrx store data only gets lost on a page refresh, however, its prob more work that you don't need right now

Comment: this is not exactly what I'm looking for. I need provider and services not only to store data. I also have endpoints and more stuff like this

Comment: ngrx effects allows call to endpoints and essentially to execute any code you want to retrieve data to chuck in the store, however, like i said - prob going way off on a tangent in terms of what you are trying to achieve