# Can I use a Service, provided by lazy module in the app module

Tags: angular

I define `MyService` in `LazyLoadedModule`.
Is it then possible to use this `MyService` in the `AppModule` ? Or can it just be used in the `LazyLoadedModule` itself?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cli to define a service in your lazyLoadedModule you will notice

```
@Injectable({ 
    providedIn: 'root'
})
```

means the service is available with the application.

Additionally you might find this answer useful [Angular: Lazy loading modules with services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186872/angular-lazy-loading-modules-with-services)

Comment: I am struggeling because when importing a lazy module I am not allowed to have the regular import statement. But when I want to use a service from the module I need to import i tthe normal way to have the auto-completion, etc. working